# How to resolve "SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService" in locally host selenium standalone server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I've executed selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar in my local machine and when I tried to 'Create Session' below mentioened error shows up in the Chrome browser.

[image]

And here's how I launched selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar in CMD

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest binary of chromedriver.exe [Chrome Driver Download](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Once your hub is started then you have start your node using below command where you need to provide `file path of your chromedriver.exe` [Windows]

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=<file path of your chromedriver.exe> -jar <file path of your selenium standalone jar file> -role node -hub <url of your hub>
```